# Deleting certain elements from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to code a program that will remove any zeros, empty strings, null, or undefined values in an array. However when I run this array: [1,null,2,3,0,-1,1.1], through the code below it returns the array with the null and 0 value still in the array. Any help?

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === '' || arr[i] === null || arr[i] === undefined) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `return arr;`, which you have placed inside your for loop. As soon as the code runs through the first element, it hits the return and leaves the function with the array as it was after the first run of the loop.

Just move the return statement outside the for loop, like so:

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === '' || arr[i] === null || arr[i] === undefined) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move  `return arr;` outside the for loop.

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === '' || arr[i] === null || arr[i] === undefined) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the falsy value to remove the unwanted items

```
function cleanArray(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function (item) {
        return !!item;
        //or return arr[i] !== 0 && arr[i] !== '' && arr[i] !== null && arr[i] !== undefined
    })
}
```

Comment: It should also be noted that this returns a new array, it does not alter the existing array.

Comment: @Oka yes... needed to negate it again

Answer (score 1):

very simplistically,

```
arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return !!item;
});
```

but that would let true and other non numeric values through

```
arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return !!item && !isNaN(item);
});
```

may work better (haven't tested it myself - leaves you with something to try)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of array filter

```
var arr = [1,null,2,3,0,-1,1.1];

var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(i){
    // if in javascript checks for truthy values
    if(i) {
     return i;   
    }
});


console.log(filteredArr); // [1, 2, 3, -1, 1.1]
```

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/xaleyixano/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function cleanArray(arr) {
    var i = 0, newArr = [];

    for (i; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i]) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);          
        }

    }
    return newArr;
}
```

This will work for sure. Hope I was helpful.
Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rok_ed/coakcd3L/